# Unable to start Cassandra Server

Tags: cassandra

While trying to start server, getting following error

D:\cassandra\apache-cassandra-3.11.4\bin>cassandra.bat -f
WARNING! Powershell script execution unavailable.
Please use 'powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted'
on this user-account to run cassandra with fully featured
functionality on this platform.
Starting with legacy startup options
Starting Cassandra Server
The system cannot find the path specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error posted relates to powershell specifically which operates with a "restricted" execution policy by default - this can be altered:

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser
```

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-5.1&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-Microsoft.PowerShell.Core)

If it then has an issue with files missing, the most likely problem is the JAVA_HOME not being set correcly.

I would recommend against this however and continuing down this path, it is a security risk and overall, running Cassandra in windows is less than ideal.

I would recommend using a docker image of Cassandra and run it from a docker image, opposed to on native windows. In Cassandra 4, there is no option to run it natively on windows.